# Google Maps V3 in hidden div

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have searched for this and it seems that the solutions I have found are not working for me.

The end goal is to have two tabs, one with google maps v3 (that shows by default, haven't gotten that far) and one tab that is hidden until clicked on.

I can get the tabs to work, but google maps does not show, I have used the resize and set center in the function for the tabs but still not working. I also have the width & height set to 100% (for mobile devices).

Can anyone take a look at the code and point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated! Again, the ultimate goal is to have the maps tab show on page load and then the tabs work as a user clicks them, showing the appropriate tab. But at this point the map tab doesn't even show the map.

my code can be seen at http://m.lewis-realty.net/map/test2.php?gps_lat=34.43640541614963&gps_lng=-77.5616387038574.

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what's causing the problem, but on line 94 of "functions.js", there is a javascript error -- You're missing opening and closing parens around the "if" condition.

I don't have a way to test it out right now but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I figured most of it out.

Along with the map resize that was already in my code, I added this to the tab function:

```
$('div#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).css('{display:block;width:100%;height:100%;}');
```

which changes the css style for the div you are selecting, so now the map works fine.

Answer (score -2):

When you show the tab that contains the map, remember to trigger the resize event on the map so that it can recalculate its size.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```